# How to split a video into multiple n-second GIFs?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, video-conversion

I read a lot of tutorials and I could do this command:

```
ffmpeg -t 3 -i video.mp4 -vf "fps=15,scale=360:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 output.gif
```

But it won't work to do what I want. I need to read a `video.mp4` and create multiple GIFs with two or three seconds for each two or three seconds of the video, until the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a bat file with this code

```
@echo off

FOR /L %%A IN (0,5,3600) DO (ffmpeg -ss %%A -t 3 -i "%~1" -abort_on empty_output -vf "fps=10,scale=350:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -abort_on empty_output_stream -loop 0 "output %%~nxA.gif")
```